# Differentiation of trace of matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I've came across the following function

$$f(X) := \mbox{tr} \left( \left( X^T X - A \right)^T \left(X^T X - A \right) \right)$$

where $A$ is a given matrix. I need help taking the derivative of this function w.r.t $X$. I.e, what is $\partial f(X) / \partial X ?$

Comment: Have a look at Section 2.4 of http://www.mit.edu/~wingated/stuff_i_use/matrix_cookbook.pdf

Comment: Thanks, if $M = X^T X -A$ then $f(X) = tr(M^T M)$, now can I apply the chain rule, i.e. $\frac{\partial tr (M^TM)}{ \partial M} \frac{\partial M}{\partial X} ?$ I know $\frac{\partial tr (M^TM)}{ \partial M} = 2M$, but what is $\frac{\partial M}{\partial X}$?

Answer (score 0):

The Frobenius product can be used to write the function and its differential as 
$$ \eqalign {
  f &= \|M\|^2_F  = M:M \cr\cr
 df &= 2\,M:dM \cr
    &= 2\,(X^TX-A):(dX^TX+X^TdX) \cr
    &= 2\,(X^TX-A):2\,\,{\rm sym}(X^TdX) \cr
    &= 2\,\,{\rm sym}(X^TX-A):2\,(X^TdX) \cr
    &= (2\,X^TX - A-A^T):2\,(X^TdX) \cr
    &= (4\,XX^TX - 2\,XA - 2\,XA^T):dX \cr
} $$
Since $df=\big(\frac {\partial f} {\partial X}:dX\big)\,$ the derivative must be
$$
\frac {\partial f} {\partial X} = 4\,XX^TX - 2\,XA - 2\,XA^T
$$